# Chef Cookbook for Creating User

Tags: chef-infra

I'd like to create a new user `kevin` with a password of `kevin`.

**cookbooks/make_user/recipes/default.rb**

```
user "kevin" do
  comment "default user"
  home "/home/kevin"
  shell "/bin/bash"
  password "kevin"
end
```

After provisioning my Vagrant box, I ssh'd onto the box. However, I was unable to `su` as the `kevin` user with a password of `kevin`.

```
[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 ~]$ su kevin
Password: 
su: incorrect password
```

Looking at the Chef 'users' [docs](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_user.html), I'm not sure that `password` is the right attribute to modify.

```
password    The password shadow hash. This attribute requires that 
            ruby-shadow be installed. This is part of the Debian package: 
            libshadow-ruby1.8.
```

How can I modify my above cookbook so that I can `su` as `kevin` with the same password?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As illustrated on the documentation: http://docs.opscode.com/resource_user.html#password-shadow-hash, you need to generate the shadow hash using OpenSSL:

```
openssl passwd -1 "theplaintextpassword"
```

Or if you use `mkpasswd`:

```
mkpasswd -m sha-512
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of the cookbook user resource describes how the "password" attribute is encrypted. It also described how to set the value using openssl:

- http://docs.opscode.com/resource_user.html